# Is there a function that reverts or undoes the effects of Needs?

Tags: packages, contexts

`Needs` is used to load packages. Is there a function that cleans all the `Definitions` and `Contexts` created by `Needs`, like `DontNeed["..."]`?

For example, I just want to load a package, use it to do something and then remove it from the kernel session without a reset.